# Error related with org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x

I get a error when I run my android application. Sometime it can run smoothly, but sometime it show errors like below:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
 Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Can somebody show me what is the main root cause of this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to post some specific JSON objects, or some more clues.  All this says is that you tried to parse an object that was null

Comment: can you print out your json string? Your stack trace looks like your connection is timing out

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse an object that is null.

So if you want to get rid of this error you should check to make sure the objects you are trying to serialize are valid.